# Standalone prettier, html formatter isn't properly formatting JS

Tags: prettier

I'm formatting code directly on the browser using the [Prettier Standalone version](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html).

Here is my code:

```js
import parserHtml from "prettier/parser-html";
import prettier from "prettier/standalone"

const rawHtml = `<script SameSite="None; Secure" src="https://unpkg.com/typebot-js"></script>
<div id="typebot-container" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
<script>
  Typebot.initContainer("typebot-container", {publishId: "remember-on-second-visit-iblkqj1-pw",hiddenVariables: {test: "null",}});
</script>`

const snippet = prettier.format(
    rawHtml,
    { parser: "html", plugins: [parserHtml] }
  );
```

It will output:

```
<script SameSite="None; Secure" src="https://unpkg.com/typebot-js"></script>
<div id="typebot-container" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
<script>
  Typebot.initContainer("typebot-container", {publishId: "remember-on-second-visit-iblkqj1-pw",hiddenVariables: {test: "null",}});
</script>
```

Whereas if I'm pasting the HTML code on my IDE, Prettier will correctly format the JS code:

```
<script SameSite="None; Secure" src="https://unpkg.com/typebot-js"></script>
<div id="typebot-container" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
<script>
  Typebot.initContainer("typebot-container", {
    publishId: "remember-on-second-visit-iblkqj1-pw",
    hiddenVariables: { test: "null" },
  });
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To format the embedded JavaScript syntax, you also need to load the `babel` parser:

```js
import parserBabel from "prettier/parser-babel";
// ...
const snippet = prettier.format(
  rawHtml,
  { parser: "html", plugins: [parserHtml, parserBabel] }
);
```